# Open Powerpoint in Write Mode from Excel VBA and the Save and close it

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to open a powerpoint and then save it ( not save As) and close it. The problem looks like being htat the file isopened in REad-only Mode.

The code is this

```
Sub Macro()

Dim ObjPPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim oslide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim oshape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim i As Long
Dim opath As String

Set ObjPPT = New PowerPoint.Application
opath = "G:\Kommunikation_Meetings_Actions\Audits\Lean Audits\Lean Action Tracker & Production 
Performance (VBA)\Daily KPI.pptx"
ObjPPT.Visible = msoCTrue
Set oPresentation = ObjPPT.Presentations.Open(opath, msoFalse)

 '...........

oPresentation.Save
Application.Wait "00:00:05"
oPresentation.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get an error on oPresentation.Save?  Ie, is that why you suspect the presentation is being opened Read-Only?  Have you verified that nobody else has the presentation open?  For example, what happens when you open it manually, not using code?

Comment: I sorted it out, there was a protection mode in the original file that I had to remove.Thanks